# How to find a clicked place or path VectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have an ImageView with an src type of VectorDrawable. It needs to be zoomable. Is there any way I can find which path was clicked?

Answer (score 4):

the VectorDrawable is an src type, like jpg, png web. so it dons have the way. I think you can use the imageView `onTouchEvent`, according to the click area to emit a different event.

I find a third library you can use, [RichPath](https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath).

1. first, use it in XML

```
<com.richpath.RichPathView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:vector="@drawable/vector_drawable" />
```

2. the sue `setOnPathClickListener` to control it.

```
richPathView.setOnPathClickListener(new RichPath.OnPathClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(RichPath richPath) {
       if (richPath.getName().equals("path_name")) {
           //TODO do an action when a specific path is clicked.
       }
    }
});
```

it makes it realize your function easier. for more details, you can read the project document and guide

Comment: Thank you, I've heard about this library but does it support zooming? Is there a way to combine both zooming and path determination?

Comment: @KyryloLukeniuk, you can zoom using `RichPathAnimator`, it support  `scale`

Comment: ok, that's promising, but will I be able to implement something like this? http://jsibbold.github.io/zoomage/